# Disabling subtitles within M3U playlists

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles, playlists, standards

I have hundreds of playlists, some days-long, that run on my media machine.  But if there are MKV files with subtitles VLC is displaying the subtitles all the time.  It is distracting and I have to switch machines every time to turn the subtitles off.  I don't want to disable subtitles at an app level, but within the playlists.

Logically the command line should be `EXTVLCOPT sub-track=0` (none) or `sub-track=none`, but there is a pedantic 0 offset and -1 resets the list to system default.

I want English subtitles for foreign languages that I don't know, but not for those languages that I do.

I cannot find anywhere a comprehensive specification for M3U, or even a declared group responsible for the specifications.

Comment: Would you like to recast this with more question, more detail & less rant. Your frustration is all your own. We don't need it.

Comment: Sorry you find it so confusing and emotionally upsetting.  What part confuses you?

Answer (score 0):

I've got some multi-language `.mkv` files.
Got `french` and `english` subtitles and audio tracks.
Below `.m3u` file is working for me:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTVLCOPT:audio-track-id=1
#EXTVLCOPT:sub-track-id=2
file-02.mkv
```

I haven't tried to disable it but i'm sure the syntax is `sub-track-id`

I think to disable the subtitle, it should be:

```
#EXTVLCOPT:sub-track-id=0
```

Or maybe

```
#EXTVLCOPT:sub-track-id=-1
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try these